# Having trouble with Axios and Vue3

Tags: typescript, axios, vuejs3

Could someone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong with Axios and Vue3?

I have this code which reaches out externally to get the host IP Address of the machine it is running on...

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Incoming :hostname="hostname" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import axios from 'axios'
import CustomerWaiting from "./components/Incoming.vue";
export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    Incoming,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      hostname: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
    .then((response) => {
      this.hostname = response.data.ip
    })
    console.log(this.hostname); // This is here so I can see it working.
  }
};
</script>
```

This then passes the returned data to a prop which passes it to my child component using `v:bind`. Then the child component takes the data and constructs a URL from it to pass commands to an externally attached device.

```
<template>
    <button @click="hello">HELLO</button>
    <button @click="timePlease">TIME PLEASE</button>
    <button @click="outtaHere">I AM OUTTA HERE</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import axios from 'axios';
    let self = this;
    export default({
        name: 'waiting',
        props: ['hostname'],
        methods: {
            hello() {
                axios({
                    url: `http://${self.hostname}:8989/?action=doSomething&additional=true`,
                    headers: {
                        accesstoken: 'myAccessToken'
                    }
                })
            },
            timePlease() {
                axios({
                    url: `http://${self.hostname}:8989/?action=doSomething&additional=true&anothere=true`,
                    headers: {
                        accesstoken: 'myAccessToken'
                    }
                })
            },
            outtaHere() {
                axios({
                    url: `http://${self.hostname}:8989/?action=doNothing`,
                    headers: {
                        accesstoken: 'myAccessToken'
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```

However this is creating the following errors, and I'm not quite understanding why

```
/components/CustomerWaiting.vue:33:5 Expected ";" but found ")"
31 |              }
32 |          }
33 |      })
   |       ^
34 |
```

Any help understanding what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated, I am new to Axios and newish to Vue3.

I have tried various tutorials from the internet related to error, but non seem to help me resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove parentheses from `export default`

```
export default ({
    name: 'waiting',
    props: ['hostname']
    ...
})
```

Change it to:

```
export default {
    name: 'waiting',
    props: ['hostname']
    ...
}
```